# Is it valid to use a higher API in the Android NDK than the minimum in Android Manifest?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, clang

I have an Android app that specifies a minimum API level of 15 and a target API of 17. Normally, I specify `android-15` (`<ndk>/platforms/android-15`) as my API level (via `--sysroot`) for the native portions of my application that use the Android NDK, since AFAIK the minimum should be targeted via the NDK.

However, there seems to be a bug with Clang + LLVM STL in NDK r14 where symbols like `strtold` do not get properly defined unless you use a *minimum* of `android-21` on the NDK side.

So my question is: What are the repercussions of using a `*.so` compiled for `android-21` with an APK targeted for min SDK of 15 and target SDK of 17? Can I get away with this?

Comment: Why not raise your target api to 21?  You can keep the minimum at 15, and not have to worry about there being a problem.  Are you desperately trying to avoid runtime permissions?

Comment: Runtime permissions kicks in at API 23

Comment: "However, there seems to be a bug with Clang + LLVM STL in NDK r14 where symbols like `strtold` do not get properly defined unless you use a minimum of `android-21` on the NDK side." This isn't a bug. `android-21` was the first version of Android that had `strtold`.

Comment: @DanAlbert How do you reconcile what C library functions are not available in different NDK API levels? This is very prohibitive, since I can't use newer toolchains with older APIs since they are missing certain functions that boost and STL require, especially when C++14 is turned on.

Comment: Easiest way to figure out what was available when is to read [the version script](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/libc.map.txt) (there's a similar one for libm in `../libm`). When it comes to the STL, nothing in the STL should come up as missing because libc++ is backed by libandroid_support. Are you using a custom build system? If your build system isn't using libandroid_support, that'll be the issue.

Comment: Doing the same for everything in Boost is a different story. We do have some plans for solving this generically in [our roadmap](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/Roadmap.md#NDK-r16-NDK-Compatibility-Library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no. See our [Common Problems doc](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/user/common_problems.md#Target-API-Set-Higher-Than-Device-API).

> The target API level in the NDK has a very different meaning than `targetSdkVersion` does in Java. The NDK target API level is your app's **minimum** supported API level. In `ndk-build`, this is your `APP_PLATFORM` setting.
>
> Since references to functions are (typically) resolved when a library is loaded rather than when they are first called, you cannot reference APIs that are not always present and guard their use with API level checks. If they are referred to at all, they must be present.

Somewhat longer, more pedantic answer: only in special cases where it isn't really higher. There is no android-20 in the NDK, for example. In this case, you'll fall back to android-19, so it's okay to set the NDK target API to android-20 with a `minSdkVersion` of 19 because you'll actually end up using android-19 anyway.

Comment: we seem to keep bumping into each other :-P

Comment: Does this really matter if I'm statically linking STL?

Comment: That's neither here nor there. The C library isn't statically linked.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right specifying a minimum in the ndk will include headers and link against the libraries shipped with that release of android. 
This, in theory, will be fine as long as 1.) the libraries exist in the old version and 2.) the libraries are ABI compatible with the old version. That means no breaking changes in class definitions or presence, absence or location of symbols in the binary, generally linux is quite good at preserving ABI compatibility but it isn't bulletproof and with android, google seem to add and remove things as and when they feel like it for virtually no reason. They certainly don't advertise when they break or preserve ABI compatibility in older versions.

<s>I think modern versions of android will also warn you in the loadlibrary code if you try and load libraries linked against newer platforms. Which doesn't look good.</s> (I must've imagined this)

All this conspires to say you probably shouldn't do it. <s>In your case I would probably recommend not using the LLVM STL (or linking it statically), since that is the source of the undefined symbols, the LLVM STL did not ship on devices before platform 21, so you cannot link against it and target those devices.</s>

Comment: Your second and third paragraphs simply are not correct. The NDK STLs are not shipped on the device at all, but with the user's app. libc++ does use things that are not available until android-21 (or even newer), but those definitions are provided by `libandroid_support` for older devices.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the point in dynamic linking the runtimes, if each app bundles their own copy? I assume they're still deduplicated in memory where possible? 
Microsoft, for example, don't like you bundling runtimes with your app. instead they prefer you to bundle the installer, to allow them to hotfix runtimes etc.

Comment: If you have multiple shared libs in your app, you need to use the shared STL rather than the static one. If you have only one shared library, you're actually better off with the static one.